# Finding Angle Given 2 Sides and 1 Angle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have heard about the rule of cosine, and other related rules, that someone said I may need to use in problems like this. I have never been exposed to these rules before, so I don't much know anything about them.

[image]

What tool am I supposed to use to be able to solve these type of questions? This seems really hard and time consuming for me, am I missing bits of knowledge that I supposed to know?

Comment: Applying the cosine ratio to a right-angled triangle is different from the rule of cosine. For this question, you only need the former.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
    \cos \alpha &= 52/61.3 \\
         \alpha &= \arccos(52/61.3) \\
    & \\
    \cos \beta &= 52/74.5 \\
         \beta &= \arccos(52/74.5)
\end{align}

Comment: how...did i not see that